# Building an URL according to values sent from multiple select boxes

Tags: php, url, parameters

I'm working at some e-commerce website where I have a bunch of filters for each product category. The filters are displayed in select boxes and each filter has more than one value.

For example if you are browsing the watches category, possible filters are: brand (Tissot, Certina, Timex), movement type (automatic, mechanic, quartz), chronograph (yes, no).

The value for each select option is a pair of filter id and filter option id, separated by a comma.

For example:

```
<label for="filter-sex">Sex</label>
<select id="filter-sex" name="filter-sex">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="1,1">For her</option>
  <option value="1,2">For him</option>
</select>

<label for="filter-brand">Brand</label>
<select id="filter-brand" name="filter-brand">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="3,10">Tissot</option>
  <option value="3,11">Certina</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to accomplish is to pass those values in the URL.

For example if I select "For her" from the filter mentioned above, my URL must look like http://www.mystore.com/watches/filters-1,2/

Then, if I select Tissot from the brand filter, the URL must look like http://www.mystore.com/watches/filters-1,2-3,10/

Any ideas how can I build that URL according to selected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have a button that when the user clicks, it takes them to the url, right?

```
$('select').change(function(){
 buildURL();
});

function buildURL(){
    var baseUrl = 'http://www.mystore.com/watches/filter';
    var url = baseUrl;
    $('select').each(function(index, value){
        if(value.value != "")
            url += '-' + value.value;
    });
    $('#url').html(url);   
}
```

For this version, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/jCq9U/

If you would like to do it server side, it would be the same logic.

```
 $baseUrl = 'http://www.mystore.com/watches/filters';
 $filterSex = $_POST['filter-sex'];
 $filterBrans = $_POST['filter-brand'];

 header('Location: ' . $baseUrl . "-" . $filterSex . "-" . $filterBrand);
```

Comment: Jose, the problem with your solution is that if I select another value from a filter previously selected, that value is added to the url but without removing the previous selected value. For example if I select "For her" from the sex filter and then I select "For him", using your solution I will have "for her" and "for him" in the url, which is not ok.

Comment: Are you using the javascript version or the php version?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle version of the one with javascript, it wan't giving me any problems.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I forgot to mention that there isn't a submit button. The form submits after a value is selected from a select box.

Comment: That looks great man! But the filters are generated from the database and so are their names. For example: "filter-" is a constant and "sex", "brand" is the filter name pulled from the database. The final filter name is "filter-sex" and "filter-brand".

Comment: Do you think you can rewrite it for PHP?